# How to export pdf on clicking Button in electron.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, electron

Did anyone worked on electron.js pdf export?
I need to export the file to pdf while clicking on button and i used ".webContents.printToPDF" but "'did-finish-load'" is not working for me.

electron version - 16
node version - 14

```
electron.ipcMain.on('exportPdf', (event, path) => {
  console.log("data-above000");
  // Use default printing options
  console.log("data-above");
  // const pdfPath = ph.join(__dirname, 'docs/new.pdf');
  mainWindow.webContents.printToPDF(options).then(data => {
    console.log("data", data);
    fs.writeFile(path, data, (error) => {
      if (error) throw error
      console.log(`Wrote PDF successfully to ${path}`)
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(`Failed to write PDF to ${path}: `, error)
  })
  console.log("data-below");
})
```

Comment: Why do you use `did-finish-load'` are you using `loadURL` or something ? Give us some code

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to export as pdf current window ?

Comment: Could you provide the Code for it and the error you get?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code updated. Please review